# Unexpected behavior of SelectionMove

Tags: bugs, front-end, cells

**Bug introduced in 11.2 or earlier, partially fixed in 12.0 and finally fixed in 13.0** [CASE:3968507]

---

<sup>(Cross-posted at [Wolfram Community](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1214368).)</sup>

I think this is a bug. If someone can help to confirm it, I'll report it to Wolfram. I can selet previous cell group:

```
SelectionMove[PreviousCell[], All, CellGroup]
```

[image]

But I fail to do this like follows

[image]

Maybe you will say that it is a `Cell` not a `CellGroup`, but why I can do this:

[image]

Can anyone give a reasonable explanation? You can get the `.nb` test file by run

```
NotebookPut[Uncompress[First[Values[Databin["fVOforSX"]]["nb"]]]]
```

Comment: @Kuba I'm sorry,I couldn't still understand why I can run normally in third case as you say.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry, I missed the point. This is the problem when one has to rewrite the code himself. Sorry again, it  indeed looks like an inconsistency. ps. Don't attach notebooks, they are not safe in general so people are not going to download it very often.

Comment: Here is my guess: `All CellGroup` is trying to reach CellGroup from the bottom, it fails so there is no selection. `Previous CellGroup` is trying to find it from the "top", so it narrows down selection up to a single cell, it fails but the cell is already selected. Just a guess.

Comment: So I'd say `All` behaves as expected and `Previous` gives you too much.

Comment: @Kuba No need to sorry,you help me all the time.:) Notebook uploading just want to reduce the amount of work for answer.I have read your [this comment](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/126997/unbehavior-of-previous#comment343534_126997) many times.Thanks for your guess,but I think this is a unexpected behavior still currently.

Comment: Yep, you can ask WRI Support.

Comment: @yode Have you contacted the support? If yes, please share their reply.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Although you tag a solved edit just now, but I can reproduce this bug still in v12...

Comment: @yode I received a letter from the support that the problem is resolved, and indeed now `SelectionMove` returns `$Failed` when it cannot move the selection in the requested way. As of the case of inconsistent behavior described in the question (I wrote about it too), they say nothing about it. I corrected the bug header.

Comment: @yode I think the bug is finally fixed in version 13.0.0. Please see the new answer.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice that some changes in the behavior of `SelectionMove` occurred on the transition from version 12.3.1 to 13.0.0.

1. Changed the behavior of `SelectionMove[EvaluationCell[], Previous, CellGroup]`. Now it selects the previous `CellGroup`, even if between the previous `CellGroup` and the `EvaluationCell[]` present several cells which aren't a member of a `CellGroup`. Here is a screenshot of a version 13.0.0 Notebook right after applying the menu item `Evaluation ► Evaluate Notebook`:

   [image: screenshot]

   And here is what happens in version 12.3.1:

   [image: SCREENSHOT2]

   The new behavior is more consistent. So the inconsistency described in the question is finally fixed in version 13.0.0.
2. In the same way changed the behavior of `SelectionMove[PreviousCell[], Previous, CellGroup]`. Now it selects the `CellGroup` before the `PreviousCell[]` even if `PreviousCell[]` is a member of a `CellGroup` itself. Here is a screenshot of a version 13.0.0 Notebook right after applying the menu item `Evaluation ► Evaluate Notebook`:

   [image: screenshot3]

   And here is what happens in version 12.3.1:

   [image: screenshot4]

So this aspect of the behavior of `SelectionMove` is finally fixed in version 13.0.0.

Answer (score 4):

This indeed looks like a bug. Citing the Documentation page for `SelectionMove`:

> `SelectionMove` returns `$Failed` if it cannot move the selection in the way you request.

In your example `SelectionMove` obviously fails but returns `Null` instead of `$Failed` what directly contradicts the Docs.

One workaround is to check whether the selection is empty (`SelectionMove` failed) and if so to attempt to select `Cell` instead of `CellGroup`:

```
SelectionMove[PreviousCell[], All, CellGroup];
If[SelectedCells[] === {},
  SelectionMove[PreviousCell[], All, Cell]];
```

Another way is to rely upon the working functionality:

```
SelectionMove[PreviousCell[], Before, CellGroup]
SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], Next, CellGroup]
```

(instead of `EvaluationNotebook[]` one can use `ParentNotebook@PreviousCell[]`).

Comment: Reported to the support as [CASE:3968507].