# How to find out if a cell is member of a closed group

Tags: notebooks, cells

I have a `While`-Loop lurking through a notebook.
I want to find out - among other things - if a cell is not visible because it is a member of a closed group.
I tried various things, see `xxx` below.
But maybe the `CurrentValue`-Aproach is not the right thing at all, maybe some `FrontEndToken`-thing would work.

Can someone help or point to the right thing.

Here is an example.
The fist cell is a `"Chapter"`-`Cell`, the second is a `"Text"`-`Cell` which is the "head" of a group which is closed via cell brackets double-click.

My favorite was `CellOpen` but it gives `True` in both cases.

```
xxx="ShowSelection"; (* Both True *)

xxx="Background"; (* Works well *)

xxx="CellOpen"; (* Both True *)

xxx="Visible";  (* Both True *)

xxx="CellGroupData";  (* Both $Failed *)

xxx="ShowClosedCellArea"; (* Both False *)

xxx="CellGroup"; (* Both $Failed *)

Row[{"Test is: ",xxx }]

SelectionMove[book,Before,Notebook];

SelectionMove[book,Next,Cell]; Last@SelectedCells[]

SelectionMove[book,Next,Cell]; Last@SelectedCells[]

CurrentValue[Last@SelectedCells[],xxx]

SelectionMove[book,Next,Cell]; Last@SelectedCells[]

CurrentValue[Last@SelectedCells[],xxx]
```

Comment: Although I would still be interested in a possible solution I figured out to use SelectionMove[..., CellGroup] and then pick the first cell from the selection. That's what I wanted, to avoid closed cells

Answer (score 1):

### Update

As was found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/261559/280), one can use `CurrentValue[cellObj, "CellGroupOpen"]` to determine the current state of a `CellGroup` containing the `CellObject` `cellObj`. It returns `Open` (if the cell group is open), `Closed` (if the cell group is closed), or `$Failed` if the `cellObj` isn't a member of a cell group:

```
Dynamic@CurrentValue[cellObj, "CellGroupOpen"]

CellPrint@Cell[
   CellGroupData[{Cell["Close me", "Subsubsection"], 
     Cell["goodbye cruel notebook", "Text"], Cell["I'll disappear too!", "Text"]}]];
cellObj = NextCell[];
```

[image: screenshot]

---

### Original answer

> My favorite was `CellOpen` but it gives `True` in both cases.

You misinterpret the meaning of the option `CellOpen`. This option is NOT related to cell grouping at all, it just hides the contents of a `Cell` when is set to `False` for that `Cell`.

One way to find out whether the cell is a member of a cell group is to attempt to select the cell group and then check whether the attempt is failed. Using the method from [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/157279/280) answer,

```
nb = CreateDocument[CellGroup[{a, b}], CellGrouping -> Manual]

cellObj = First@Cells[nb]
SelectionMove[cellObj, All, CellGroup]
If[Length@SelectedCells[nb] == 0, 
 Print["The cell is not a member of a cell group!"],
 If[MatchQ[NotebookRead[nb], Cell[CellGroupData[_, Closed | False]]], 
  Print["The cell is a member of a closed cell group!"]]]
```

Additionally one can find out whether the cell is the first cell in the group (which is the only visible cell when the group is closed via group bracket double-click):

```
"FirstCellInGroup" /. Developer`CellInformation@cellObj
```

Comment: Note that the second argument to `CellGroupData` can be a `Dynamic` expression, so that would have to be checked, too.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Do you have an idea how it could be done (I mean, obtaining the value of `Dynamic` expression)?

Comment: That's a hard question. The simplest option is `Setting` but in general dynamic evaluation obviously can depend on the cell evaluating it and all sorts of other factors. I've seen ``Internal`DynamicEvaluate`` before but don't know how to make it work.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Simple application of `Setting` to the output of `NotebookRead` fails, tried with `nb = CreateDocument[CellGroup[{Dynamic[a], b}, Dynamic[a]], 
  CellGrouping -> Manual]`. The problem seems to be hard indeed.